# Cannot include a cell-formula into VBA code in MS Excel

Tags: formula

I am trying a simple VBA program, that looks like this:

```
Function NotWorking() As Single

 If Range("C3") = 0 Then
 NotWorking = "=0.6*7"
 Else
 NotWorking = 1.2
 End If

End Function
```

If cell ***C3*** has ***0*** as a value, the function ***NotWorking*** has to return in the current cell the result of ***=0.6*7***, which is ***4,2***. If the value in ***C3*** is not ***0***, then the current cell has to return ***1,2***.

In my case, things aren't the way I expected. In the current cell I type ***=NotWorking()***. If ***C3*** is anything but ***0***, I obtain ***1,2***, but when I appropriate ***0*** to ***C3***, the current cell returns ***#VALUE***.

Why does this code not work?

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I notice that `"=0.6*7"` is a string, not a number, but `1.2` *is* a number.

You have specified that the function returns a single, but `"=0.6*7"` isn't a single.

Comment: How do you include a cell formula into a VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to return it from the routine, but reach out to the sheet from within the routine.

```
Sub NotWorking()

   Dim src As Range
   Dim dst As Range

   Set src = Range("C3")
   Set dst = Range("E3")

   If src.Value = 0 Then
       dst.Formula = "=0.6 * 7"
   Else
       dst.Value = 1.2
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Very well. This works really nice. Have an upvote. I still need something slightly different - a formula, that could be called on every cell and every sheet of the file. I guess this little video will help me (as well as your code) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=317P-hH0QwM. Greetings. :)

Comment: You said "Have an upvote," but the voting stands at zero ... :(

Comment: That is, unfortunately, correct. I have rating under 15. Every upvote I give is written down in the database and after (if) I reach rating of 15 or more, the upvotes, I have given, will appear. :)

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks for the explanation.  So all is NOT vanity!